# Iframe and bootstrap collapse menu height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have an iframe which I need to put at different websites so I need to use only javascript not jquery. Inside that I frame I put page with twitter bootrap collapse menu... so its looks like this:

```
function Book(www){
    function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height = (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width = (newwidth) + "px";
};

    var content = '<iframe id="iframe1" src="'+www+'" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none; position: fixed;left: 0px;width: 300px; top: 30%;z-index: 9999999;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" width="100%" onLoad="autoResize(iframe1);"></iframe><a style="display:none;" href="http://aaa.com" rel="ext">aaa</a>';

var newNode = document.createElement("DIV");  
newNode.innerHTML = content;
document.body.appendChild(newNode); 


};
```

Inside Collapse menu I have dinamicly added data - table and now when I try to use this iframe I dont get right height... so height is not good and user need to scroll inside iframe...

How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: You specify in your question no jquery...why include the jquery tag?

Comment: sorry I will remove it